# NLTK punkt sentence tokenizer splitting on numeric bullets

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am using nltk PunktSentenceTokenizer for splitting paragraphs into sentences. I have paragraphs as follows:

paragraphs = "1. Candidate is very poor in mathematics. 2. Interpersonal skills are good. 3. Very enthusiastic about social work"

**Output:**
['1.', 'Candidate is very poor in mathematics.', '2.', 'Interpersonal skills are good.', '3.', 'Very enthusiastic about social work']

I tried to add sent starters using below code but that didnt even work out.

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer
tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer()
tokenizer._params.sent_starters.add('1.')
```

I really appreciate if anybody could drive me towards correct direction

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the output that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The use of regular expressions can provide a solution to this type of problem, as illustrated by the code below:

```
paragraphs = "1. Candidate is very poor in mathematics. 2. Interpersonal skills are good. 3. Very enthusiastic about social work" 

import re
reSentenceEnd = re.compile("\.|$")
reAtLeastTwoLetters = re.compile("[a-zA-Z]{2}")

previousMatch = 0
sentenceStart = 0
end = len(paragraphs)
while(True):
    candidateSentenceEnd = reSentenceEnd.search(paragraphs, previousMatch)

    # A sentence must contain at least two consecutive letters:
    if reAtLeastTwoLetters.search(paragraphs[sentenceStart:candidateSentenceEnd.end()]) :
        print(paragraphs[sentenceStart:candidateSentenceEnd.end()])
        sentenceStart = candidateSentenceEnd.end()

    if candidateSentenceEnd.end() == end:
        break
    previousMatch=candidateSentenceEnd.start() + 1
```

the output is:

> 1. Candidate is very poor in mathematics.
> 2. Interpersonal skills are good.
> 3. Very enthusiastic about social work

Many tokenizers including (nltk and Spacy) can handle regular expressions. Adapting this code to their framework might not be trivial though.